# Profile Memory Allocation in Python (with support for Numpy arrays)

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, profile

I have a program that contains a large number of objects, many of them Numpy arrays. My program is swapping miserably, and I'm trying to reduce the memory usage, because it actually can't finis on my system with the current memory requirements.

I am looking for a nice profiler that would allow me to check the amount of memory consumed by various objects (I'm envisioning a memory counterpart to cProfile) so that I know where to optimize.

I've heard decent things about Heapy, but Heapy unfortunately does not support Numpy arrays, and most of my program involves Numpy arrays.

Comment: not your (good) question, but you can of course use lots of dtype=np.float32 / .astype(np.float32) for 32-bit instead of 64-bit floats.  (Beware of functions that silently do 32 in -> 64 out.)

Answer (score 12):

One way to tackle the problem if you are calling lots of different functions and you are unsure where the swapping comes from would be to use the new plotting functionality from [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler). First you must decorate the different functions you are using with @profile. For simplicity I'll use the example [examples/numpy_example.py](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/blob/master/examples/numpy_example.py) shipped with memory_profiler that contains two functions: `create_data()` and `process_data()`

To run your script, instead of running it with the Python interpreter, you use the mprof executable, that is

```
$ mprof run examples/numpy_example.py
```

This will create a file called `mprofile_??????????.dat`, where the ? will hold numbers representing the current date. To plot the result, simply type `mprof plot` and it will generate a plot similar to this (if you have several .dat files it will always take the last one):

[image: output of memory_profiler's mprof]

Here you see the memory consumption, with brackets indicating when you enter/leave the current function. This way it is easy to see that function `process_data()` has a peak 
 of memory consumption. To further dig into your function, you could use the line-by-line profiler to see the memory consumption of each line in your function. This is run with

```
python -m memory_profiler examples/nump_example.py
```

This would give you an output similar to this:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    13                             @profile
    14  223.414 MiB    0.000 MiB   def process_data(data):
    15  414.531 MiB  191.117 MiB       data = np.concatenate(data)
    16  614.621 MiB  200.090 MiB       detrended = scipy.signal.detrend(data, axis=0)
    17  614.621 MiB    0.000 MiB       return detrended
```

where it is clear that scipy.signal.detrend is allocating a huge amount of memory.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [memory profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler). It provides line by line profiling and `Ipython` integration, which makes it very easy to use it:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: %memit np.zeros(1e7)
maximum of 3: 70.847656 MB per loop
```

**Update**

As mentioned by @WickedGrey there seems to be a bug ([see github issue tracker](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/issues/9)) when calling a function more than one time, which I can reproduce:

```
In [2]: for i in range(10):
   ...:     %memit np.zeros(1e7)
   ...:     
maximum of 1: 70.894531 MB per loop
maximum of 1: 70.894531 MB per loop
maximum of 1: 70.894531 MB per loop
maximum of 1: 70.894531 MB per loop
maximum of 1: 70.894531 MB per loop
maximum of 1: 70.894531 MB per loop
maximum of 1: 70.902344 MB per loop
maximum of 1: 70.902344 MB per loop
maximum of 1: 70.902344 MB per loop
maximum of 1: 70.902344 MB per loop
```

However I don't know to what extend the results maybe influenced (seems to be not that much in my example, so depending on your use case it maybe still useful) and when this issue maybe fixed. I asked that at [github](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/issues/9#issuecomment-26115349).

Comment: https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/issues/9 ("wrong results when calling function twice") seems like it makes this a non-starter for any serious application.  Am I misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: @WickedGrey Maybe you are right, I never used `memory_profiler` before, just read about it, but I can reproduce this bug now. Updated my answer.

Comment: Since memory_profiler queries the OS to have the amount of memory used, it is not unlikely to have slightly different results in different runs since this might be contaminated by things such as IPython history or just the way Python allocates memory (you never know for sure when that memory is goint to be released). Therefore, a difference of less than 1% in the results does not seem unlikely to me.

Comment: Can anyone comment on the status of the multiple call bug in 2018? The github issue link is broken. I tried memory_profiler and it seemed potentially useful but the results were gibberish in my (multiple invocation) example, not something that was off by a small amount. The memory usage was plausible, the increment certainly off.

Answer (score 1):

Since numpy 1.7 there exists a semi built-in way to track memory allocations:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/tools/allocation_tracking

Comment: Holy crap, that's super useful.  Thanks!  I had a function whose max memory usage was scaling with the size of its input data by a factor of 12x.  But now, thanks to that `track_allocations.py` script, I got it down to just 4x, so I won't see those pesky `MemoryError`s any more.  Phew!  Lovely to have that in my toolbox now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just save/pickle some of the arrays to disk in tmp files when not using them? That's what I've had to do in the past with large arrays. Of course this will slow the program down, but at least it'll finish. Unless you need them all at once?

Comment: Well, yes, but the whole point of profiling is that I want to figure out *which* arrays I should write to file. If I try to write everything and pull it only when I need it, the I/O requirements would be enormous, and it would defeat the point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `valgrind` with the `massif` tool?

```
valgrind --tool=massif python yourscript.py
```

it will create a file called `massif.out.xxx` which you can inspect via

```
ms_print massif.out.xxx | less
```

it has all kinds of useful information, but the plot right in the beginning should be what you're looking for. Also check out [massif tutorial](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) on the valgrind homepage.

Using `valgrind` is quite advanced and there might be easier ways to do what you're looking for.