# Reducing numpy memory footprint in long-running application

Tags: python, memory-management, numpy, garbage-collection

In my application one hundred numpy arrays (1000 complex elements each) are generated and filled with data. Then over many iterations, the array elements are modified over and over again. After the initial generation, the system monitor reports around 50 Mb of RAM usage. Although I am not generating any new arrays, the footprint keeps growing by around 40 Mb per iteration.

I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018986/memory-profiler-for-numpy), that the garbage collector does not handle numpy arrays. So I assume that some temporary arrays I am generating to manipulate data are not collected correctly.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372444/profile-memory-allocation-in-python-with-support-for-numpy-arrays?lq=1) it says that guppy.hpy().heap() does not help with profiling numpy, unfortunately.

How can I identify the source of the problem and ideally keep consumption constant over any number of iterations?

I suspect that I may be generating copies when assigning array elements as described [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values), which are then not garbage collected.

Can I manually dispose of temporary numpy arrays to assist garbage collection?

[Update 1]: Sample code

This bit of code is called thousands of times. Each time, the footprint increases. I cannot see why, because to my understanding it is only reading existing arrays and manipulating other existing arrays. Are any of these slicing operations doing something unintended? (Sorry for the line length. I can simplify it, but then I might be hiding my errors, too.)

```
for ts in np.arange(numTimeslots):
            for fc in np.arange(numFreqChunks):
                interfencep = np.sum( np.dot(np.dot(self.baseStations[bs].cells[cell].CSI_OFDMA[:,:,fc,ts] ,np.diag(cell.OFDMA_power[:,fc,ts])),self.baseStations[bs].cells[cell].CSI_OFDMA[:,:,fc,ts].conj().T) for bs in self.baseStations for cell in bs.cells if cell != self._cell) 
                noisep = np.eye(self.antennas) * (self.noisePower / numFreqChunks)
                self.OFDMA_interferenceCovar[:,:,fc,ts] = noisep + interfencep
                self.OFDMA_EC[:,:,fc,ts] = (np.dot(np.dot(self.OFDMA_CSI[:,:,fc,ts],linalg.inv(noisep+interfencep)),self.OFDMA_CSI[:,:,fc,ts].conj().T))
                eigs = linalg.eig(self.OFDMA_EC[:,:,fc,ts])[0]
                self.OFDMA_SINR[:,fc,ts] = np.real(eigs)
```

[Update 2]: For those curious, this is part of a mobile network simulator. Running on virtualenv, Python 2.7.3, Numpy 1.6.2, SciPy 0.11.0b1

[Update 3]: Via commenting it and checking the system monitor, I can identify the 'interferencep = ...'-line as a culprit. It allocated significant memory which is not freed. But why?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a simple code example?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't been able to narrow it down within the program.

Comment: What data type are the elements?

Comment: I thought I added a comment requesting the version of numpy you're running against and if you've checked against the latest release and development branches.

Comment: Python 2.7.3, Numpy 1.6.2, SciPy 0.11.0b1. I have not checked against the new beta releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via using the system monitor and code inspection/commenting, I found the memory leak. It was caused by comparing a numpy array with an empty list in a different file. I will dig into the leak in a different place and vote to delete this question as I find it too specific to assist anyone else.

[Update 1]: New question describing the source of the problem:
[Why does comparison of a numpy array with a list consume so much memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461413/why-does-comparison-of-a-numpy-array-with-a-list-consume-so-much-memory)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same kind of issue. Unfortunately I found no workaround. The only thing that worked for me was to refactor the code into small isolated function. Those functions should be made so that I can convince myself I keep no references to arrays that keep the garbage collector from collecting arrays. You should take special care to array views which are generated by slicing, etc ...

In order to make code more memory efficient and less prone to memory leaks, I often found usefull to use the out= keyword argument provided by many numpy functions.

Comment: I thought I did the same. Lots of modules and individual function call around the core data objects. All that's happening inside those modules should be garbage collected. Where could memory possibly increase?

Comment: As a last resort, you can centralize memory allocation of your arrays in one place and working in-place in all other functions. Also, you can try to explicitly del some suspicious arrays. Finally, you could very well be hit by a numpy memory leak.