# Why does comparison of a numpy array with a list consume so much memory?

Tags: python, arrays, list, memory-management, numpy

This bit stung me recently. I solved it by removing all comparisons of numpy arrays with lists from the code. But why does the garbage collector miss to collect it?

Run this and watch it eat your memory:

```
import numpy as np
r = np.random.rand(2)   
l = []
while True:
    r == l
```

Running on 64bit Ubuntu 10.04, virtualenv 1.7.2, Python 2.7.3, Numpy 1.6.2

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Where you running this in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: Same in both script and console.

Comment: I can reproduce it, sounds like a bug in numpy, best report it I think, probably some reference counting got wrong inside numpy.

Comment: @larsmans Reproduced with 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7.3, numpy 1.6.2 both running an IDE and a script on the command line.

Comment: For the record: Python 2.6.6, NumPy 1.4.1.

Comment: Alright, after your confirmation I submitted a ticket to the numpy trac.

Comment: For the curious, @Hauke's bug report is http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2216 - one of the devs found a C-level probable reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles on this and wonders...

@Dugal yes, I believe this is a memory leak in current numpy versions (Sept. 2012) that occurs when some Exceptions are raised (see [this](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2216) and [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/449)). Why adding the `gc` call that @BiRico did "fixes" it seems weird to me, though it must be done right after appearently? Maybe its an oddity with how python garbage collects tracebacks, if someone knows the Exception handling and garbage colleciton CPython Internals, I would be interested.

**Workaround**: This is not directly related to lists, but for example most broadcasting Exceptions (the empty list does not fit to the arrays size, an empty array results in the same leak. Note that internally there is an Exception prepared that never surfaces). So as a workaround, you should probably just check first if the shape is correct (if you do it a lot, otherwise I wouldn't worry really, this leaks just a small string if I got it right).

**FIXED:** This issue will be fixed with numpy 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot give a more complete answer, but this seems to have something to do with garbage collection. I was able to recreate this issue using python 2.7.2, numpy 1.6.1 on Redhat 5.8. However when I tried the following, memory usage went back to normal.

```
import gc
import numpy as np
r = np.random.rand(2)   
l = []
while True:
    r == l
    gc.collect()
```