# Detect swapping in python

Tags: python, memory

What is the best way to determine if the computer running my script is using swap memory? It should be as cross-platform as possible. One solution would be to run a program like `top` as a subprocess, but I would hope there's a better way.

Comment: The command `free -m` might be of interest to you, as seen in [this article on nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/), section *How do I verify swap is activated or not?*

Comment: The most crossplatform method is occupy and fill memory untill you got exception, and at the end catch exception and print `I use swap memory`

Comment: You can use `psutil`. It is not in the standard library but it is cross platform. You can get info on swap memory using `psutil.swap_memory()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the module `psutil`. It is not a module in standard library though and you have to install it using `pip` package manager.

```
pip install psutil
```

The swap usage data can be gathered using `psutil.swap_memory()`. It returns a named tuple.

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.swap_memory()
sswap(total=2097147904L, used=886620160L, free=1210527744L, percent=42.3, sin=1050411008, sout=1906720768)
```

Answer (score 5):

I saw in this thread [Stackoverflow: Profile Memory Allocation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372444/profile-memory-allocation-in-python-with-support-for-numpy-arrays) an explanation of how you can record the use of your memory in real time. Then directly printed into a nice graph using `mrpof`. (The thread is a bit old but still accurate I guess).

Here is the official documentation of the module: [memory profiler pypi documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler)

If you don't want to read the documentation, you first have to install the package via:

```
$ easy_install -U memory_profiler # pip install -U memory_profiler
```

And then use it on a script like this:

```
$ mprof run you_script_python.py
$ mprof plot
```

Which produce a file like this: ([source](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2014/plot-memory-usage-as-a-function-of-time/))

[image: mprof_example]

Or more simply like this:

```
$ python -m memory_profiler you_script_python.py
```

Will produce the following output:

```
Line #    Mem usage  Increment   Line Contents
 ==============================================
 3                           @profile
 4      5.97 MB    0.00 MB   def my_func():
 5     13.61 MB    7.64 MB       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
 6    166.20 MB  152.59 MB       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
 7     13.61 MB -152.59 MB       del b
 8     13.61 MB    0.00 MB       return a
```

It also works on windows. According to the author, Fabian Pedregosa, the module `memory profiler` is cross-platform: [Stackoverflow: Which Python memory profiler is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended)

Sorry for all the links!